# TRK0002 error in VS 2017 with Android NDK r17b

Tags: xamarin.android, android-ndk

Our mobile application is built on Xamarin platform under VS 2017.

Here is my setup that works for building Android native libraries:

```
Options->Xamarin->Android Settings->NDK-Location =
   C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b

Option->Cross Platform->C++->Android->NDK-Location = 
   C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b
```

With this setting, my native x86 Android library builds just fine from within VS 2017.

I am now trying to use the newer version of ndk. I downloaded android-ndk-r17b-windows-x86_64.zip and unzipped it into C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r17b folder. I also updated the above two settings to reflect the location. However, now when I try to rebuild my native library project, I get the following error:

```
TRACKER : error TRK0002: Failed to execute command:
"C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r17b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe 
@C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9073b0f118b8483b8ebaec8a2cd4e994.rsp". 

The handle is invalid.
```

I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.